# How to get image name, mime type, width, height, file size from post custom field?

Tags: images

What I need is some function to echo file name of image used in post like "image-file-name.jpg", or just "image-file-name".

Also it would be great to be able to have even more information about image like:

- image width,
- image height,
- image mime type / format,
- image file size,
- image extension.

Also this may be helpful, I have custom field named 'image_full_url' which contains full url address of image used in post. For example content of custom field named 'image_full_url' is:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/image-file-name.jpg
```

I am using that custom field to echo that URL when I need it, and it would be nice to have something similar to echo other data about image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file from your Url like this:

```
//get the URL from your Metafield, $post is your current Post
$image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_your_image_url_meta', true );

//set up a query to search your posts table for the Url         
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid = %s LIMIT 1";

//prepare and launch the query
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $image ) );

//if there are results
if ( count ( $result ) > 0 ) {

    $image_id = $result['0']->ID;

    //get the image data
    $image_data = get_post_meta( $image_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );

}
```

All the information you need should now be available in `$image_data`. Keep in mind that you may need to change the script a little bit - for example if your Authors put in a thumbnail-url, you have to clean it first and change the query to a `LIKE` statement.

Comment: Nothing happens when I put this code in single.php file...

Comment: Did you change the key of the metafield? Can you echo the $image variable? Also note that this code does not produce any output..

Answer (score 0):

If you have declare every field of image in custom field. Use following code for getting all post custom feild data;

```
<?php 
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
 $postid=$post->ID;
 $all_meta_for_post = get_post_meta( $postid );    
 endwhile; 
?>
```

Comment: The question is not about how to get custom fields data but rather getting data about the image.

Comment: After inserting that code in my single.php file nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong??